# How to serialize generic case classes with µPickle?

Tags: scala, serialization, upickle

The [µPickle docs](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/) say generic case classes can be serialized:

> Out of the box, uPickle supports writing and reading the following types:
>
> - Stand-alone `case class`es and `case object`s, and their generic equivalents,

However no example is given and I was unable to find a correct way so far. My attempt is:

```
import upickle.default._

object Container {
  implicit def rw[T]: ReadWriter[Container[T]] = macroRW
}
case class Container[T](value: T)

object Main extends App {
  val c = new Container(0)

  val cString = write(c)
  println("c " + cString)
}
```

This fails with error:

> Error:(7, 50) could not find implicit value for parameter e:
>
> upickle.default.Reader[T]
>
> implicit def rw[T]: ReadWriter[Container[T]] = macroRW

How should generic case classes be serialized using µPickle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to use context bound

```
implicit def rw[T: ReadWriter]: ReadWriter[Container[T]] = macroRW
```